# Setting Canvas As Background

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

At the moment I have a canvas image that walks around changing colour with JavaScript.  I am trying to set it as my background, and failing.

I have followed this Google Developers guide but it seems too simple - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/12/Canvas-driven-background-images?hl=en.

This is my script:

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext('2d', 'animation', 300, 300);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var processing = new Processing(canvas, function(processing) {
        processing.size(innerWidth, innerHeight);
        processing.background(0xFFF);

        var mouseIsPressed = false;
        processing.mousePressed = function () { mouseIsPressed = true; };
        processing.mouseReleased = function () { mouseIsPressed = false; };

        var keyIsPressed = false;
        processing.keyPressed = function () { keyIsPressed = true; };
        processing.keyReleased = function () { keyIsPressed = false; };

        function getImage(s) {
            var url = "https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/" + s + ".png";
            processing.externals.sketch.imageCache.add(url);
            return processing.loadImage(url);
        }

        with (processing) {

    var Walker = function() {
        this.x = width/2;
        this.y = height/2;
        this.walkSpeed = 10;
        this.r = random(100,255);
        this.g = random(100,255);
        this.b = random(100,255);
        this.colorStep = 5;
    };

Walker.prototype.display = function() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.r, this.g, this.b);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
};

Walker.prototype.changeColor = function() {
    this.r+=(random(0,2)-1)*this.colorStep;
    this.g+=(random(0,2)-1)*this.colorStep;
    this.b+=(random(0,2)-1)*this.colorStep;
};

// Randomly move up, down, left, right, or stay in one place
Walker.prototype.walk = function() {
    var choice = floor(random(4));
    if(this.x<=0||this.x>=width) {
        this.x=width/2;
    }
    if(this.y<=0||this.y>=height) {
        this.y=height/2;
    }
    if (choice === 0) {
        this.x+=this.walkSpeed;
    } else if (choice === 1) {
        this.x-=this.walkSpeed;
    } else if (choice === 2) {
        this.y+=this.walkSpeed;
    } else {
        this.y-=this.walkSpeed;
    } 
};

var w = new Walker();

var draw = function() {
    w.walk();
    w.changeColor();
    w.display();
};

        }
        if (typeof draw !== 'undefined') processing.draw = draw;
    });

</script>
```

The site is at http://worldofwinfield.co.uk/

Please go easy on me - I am a beginner!

Thanks
James

Answer (score 1):

You could use absolute positioning and z-index to make your canvas into a background. Example (using a different animation):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s8f6LqLz/

```js
var sun = new Image();
var moon = new Image();
var earth = new Image();
function init(){
  sun.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1456/Canvas_sun.png';
  moon.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1443/Canvas_moon.png';
  earth.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/1429/Canvas_earth.png';
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300); // clear canvas

  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,153,255,0.4)';
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(150,150);

  // Earth
  var time = new Date();
  ctx.rotate( ((2*Math.PI)/60)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/60000)*time.getMilliseconds() );
  ctx.translate(105,0);
  ctx.fillRect(0,-12,50,24); // Shadow
  ctx.drawImage(earth,-12,-12);

  // Moon
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate( ((2*Math.PI)/6)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/6000)*time.getMilliseconds() );
  ctx.translate(0,28.5);
  ctx.drawImage(moon,-3.5,-3.5);
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.restore();
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(150,150,105,0,Math.PI*2,false); // Earth orbit
  ctx.stroke();
 
  ctx.drawImage(sun,0,0,300,300);

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

init();
```

```css
.canvas-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.canvas-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
    <div class="canvas-overlay">Hi, I'm content above the canvas :)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it does now fall under the rest of the site, however it is stopping me from minimising the first two elements of my accordion.  Any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure about the accordion, I'd have to see it.

Comment: I'd start at console errors. I see one when loading your site: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).novacancy is not a function

Comment: Ah cool, I didn't know about the JavaScript console.  I have deleted what was causing the error - something I was previously playing with but gave up on.